# Numpy multi-dimensional array slicing from end to first

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

From a numpy array

```
a=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
```

I want to obtain an array

```
[[99, 90, 91],
 [9, 0, 1],
 [19, 10, 11]]
```

I tried

```
a[[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]
```

but this instead gives `array([99,  0, 11])`. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: its called numpy slicing... just google it you will find everything you need to know. To answer your question quickly you probably want to something like a[3:7,5:9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the slicing into two seperate operations

```
arr[ [ -1,0,1] ][ :, [ -1,0,1]]
# array([[99., 90., 91.],
#        [ 9.,  0.,  1.],
#        [19., 10., 11.]])
```

Equivalent to:

```
temp = arr[ [ -1,0,1] ]  # Extract the rows
temp[ :, [ -1,0,1]]      # Extract the columns from those rows
# array([[99., 90., 91.],
#        [ 9.,  0.,  1.],
#        [19., 10., 11.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[[-1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]` This is wrong, this means you want an elements from `row -1`, `column -1` i.e `(99)` and `row 0`, `column 0` i.e `(0)` and `row 1`, `column 1` i.e `(11)` this is the reason you are getting array([99, 0, 11])

**Your Answer:**

`a[ [[-1],[0],[1]], [-1,0,1] ]`: This means, we want every element from column `-1, 0, 1` from row `[-1], [0], [1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Roll your array over two axis and slice 3x3:

```
>>> np.roll(a, shift=1, axis=[0,1])[:3, :3]
array([[99, 90, 91],
       [ 9,  0,  1],
       [19, 10, 11]])
```